# cin.get() causes access violation error under Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, access-violation

My Visual Studio 2013 console application has suddenly started causing an access violation error just before exiting.  The popup error window tells me "Access violation executing location xxx" and it breaks in the VC library function _callthreadstartex.  If I comment out the lines I added:

> cout << "\nHit Enter to finish\n";
>
> std::cin.get();

it works.  Also, when I run it from a command window instead of from the Visual Studio debug environment, it works.  (The project file I'm working with does not contain a Release configuration--debug version is all there is.)

The rest of the program is an example from a large open source package, which is too elaborate to list here.  The operating system is Windows 7, freshly installed on an older computer.

While I know that this type of error is usually cryptic and intermittent and may not have anything to do with cin.get() at all, can I rule anything in or out?  Since the only things I added are standard library calls, programming error on my part is not likely.  The package I'm working with is very complex and fragile, but I don't know where to start in using the error information I'm given to track down the problem.  Is it possible this is an operating system setting matter that doesn't require a code fix?  Is it a threading issue that's outside my expertise?

Comment: This is usually not enough information to find the bug. Usually it is memory management related (using pointers pointing to invalid data, deleting a pointer multiple times, etc.)